# Box Shadow in Firefox

Tags: css

I have a problem with `box-shadow` in Firefox - it "lags":

This is my CSS:

```
-moz-box-shadow : 0 0 5px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow : 0 0 5px #333;
box-shadow : 0 0 5px #333;
```

In Chrome, it works normally (without "lag"), but in Firefox it's slow.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Chrome is optimized for CSS3. Have you tried The beta version of Firefox?

Comment: More detail is needed here. How many elements are you applying this to? What version of Firefox? Could you make an example of the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? @Donut: Sorry, bad timing with the edits.

Comment: certainly my installation of Mozilla 3.6.1.3 has no problem with `box-shadow` rendering or indeed lagging.

Comment: try to use hsla() coloring. like this : -moz-box-shadow:0 0 1em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1.0);

Comment: what do you mean it lags? It runs with no problem on many of the solutions I have made. What Firfow version are you using?

Comment: @Gunslinger Why? Does HSLA perform better then HEX? (And why HSLA, and not just HSL?)

Comment: @Shaz : optimized my AXE :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15295389/1654265

Answer (score 7):

This has been a known bug in Firefox for years. Box-shadow can cause slow scrolling or, when you are animating an element to which box-shadow is assigned, Firefox can crawl. The fix is to eiher restrict blur radius to 10px or filter out the box-shadow from Firefox:

```
.fubar {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:none !important;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .fubar {
        box-shadow:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: `This has been a known bug in Firefox for years` centuries now

Comment: Alas, while the bug is still present in FireFox, the worakround no longer works as FireFox dropped support for -moz-box-shadow...