# grid lines - background-size limit when using linear-gradient?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

Is there some kind of limit on `background-size` in Chromium/Google Chrome?

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kc9d6k54/3/

[image]

I am trying to implement gridlines of different intervals, this works to a point, but in this example when I go past `256px` the second part of the linear gradient disappears.

Example code:

```
.grid-lines div {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(0deg, #900 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), 
        linear-gradient(0deg, #bbf 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;                    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

...

.grid-lines .fifth {
    background-size: 1px 320px, 1px 40px;
    left: 600px;
}
```

**Q1:** Why does this happen?

**Q2:** What workarounds could I apply/alternative approaches could I use to get the effect I desire (basically intervals at `320px` and `480px`)

**BONUS Q:** Why does the dark red line appear fainter for the 160px column?

Comment: It works perfectly for me in Firefox. The error is reproducible in Chrome only. Worth adding it in the tags

Comment: BTW nice question, +1

Comment: thanks, yes it does work perfectly in IE as well.

Comment: Not the first [strange behaviour of Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15295389/1654265) I've seen, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when doing a grid for a midi editor. I needed vertical lines for Bar, Quarter note and subdivisions that could be changed depending on time signature.

Thanks to your observation, I tried a 2px setting for the bar marker. Seems that Chrome tries to scale proportionally (slightly).

```
.grid-lines div {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(0deg, #900 0, transparent 2px), 
        linear-gradient(0deg, #bbf 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;                    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b239Ldrv/