# Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'. Declaration dropped

Tags: firefox, css

Suddenly what happened to CSS `-moz-box-shadow`? In my design the Firefox console appeared with a strange problem:

[image: Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'. Declaration dropped.]

But as per the [CSS Box Shadow rules](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) I followed all the rules, then what happened? Here is the block where it's directing:

```
div.area {
  margin: 2px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #ccc;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #ccc;
     box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #ccc;
  margin-top: -80px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}
```

I tried the following too:

```
div.area {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ccc;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ccc;
         box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ccc;
}
```

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 20.0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Firefox supports `box-shadow` so well, it has no reason to keep `-moz-box-shadow` around. It dropped support for the prefix in version 13, so if you're really that concerned about a warning and don't mind losing support for older versions of Firefox, you can remove that declaration. Likewise for `-webkit-box-shadow` for recent versions of WebKit browsers.

Comment: One use case would be to get around the old FireFox performance bug where large box shadows make scrolling slow (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095253/box-shadow-in-firefox), as this bug still hasn't been addressed...

Comment: Mozilla developers seem not to like "backwards compatibility" concept...

Comment: Prefixed properties as experimental implementations of standards by their very nature were not meant to be backwards compatible in the first place, so that argument is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

`box-shadow` does not require any prefixes since more than an year ago (firefox 4 and chrome 10): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 2):

**In file .css You just Find and replay moz  to webkit**

Example

```
-moz-box-shadow  **to** -webkit-box-shadow

-moz-border-radius **to** -webkit-border-radius

-moz-border-top-left-radius **to** -webkit-border-top-left-radius
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest versions of most of the browsers, you do not need to use -moz-box-shadow.

You can simply use box-shadow.

Read more about it on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)