# ext js error messages in console debug on startup (from css section)

Tags: extjs

any ideas why I am getting all these error messages.  I am not doing ANY styling yet.  Just whatever is included in standard startup.

[image: app watch]
[image: console]

Comment: Check this thread for your reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479928/unknown-property-moz-box-shadow-declaration-dropped

Comment: it says there is no reason to keep these unknown properties around.  I'm not even declaring them anywhere... could it be in the project creation code somewhere?  how do I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are part of the Extjs theme your project is using.. I don't think this would cause any problem.

You can find the name of the theme in your app.json file and you can find the corresponding theme in your extjs library directory